# How do I get a Mew?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

Mew is my favorite Pokémon, and I love Pokémon Rumble World. So, I was wondering if I can get a Mew in Pokémon Rumble World. Is there a way?

Comment: Please answer is not neccecary. Capitalising every word is annoying.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to stop.

Answer (score 3):

Mew spawns randomly at the [Bastion of Beginnings](http://www.serebii.net/rumbleworld/locations/legendterrain.shtml#bastionofbeginnings), in the [Legend Terrain area](http://www.serebii.net/rumbleworld/locations/legendterrain.shtml). You don't need any stars to have a chance of finding it.

To get the Legend Balloon, you must have an Adventure Rank greater or equal to 50, and buy it in the Balloon Shop for 200 PokéDiamonds.

Comment: How can I get the Legend Balloon?

Comment: @PokemonMaster: I've edited my answer with more details.